Como puedo arreglar el (Undefined array key 1)
Estoy haciendo varias sesiones en un carrito de compras en donde si existe una sesion llamada carrito me lo muestre la id y el contenido de este producto en el carrito ademas de incrementarse; y si no hay registro lo muestre mediante un arreglo que indicara los detalles del producto, se que es mucho codigo pero no se como solucionar ese array si estoy guardando todo dentro de las sesiones (tengo una sesion del carrito que guarda un arreglo en caso de no existir una id; tambien un arreglo nuevo que si exste lo guarde dentro ) aqui mi codigo de la sesion:


<?php
session_start();
include('./php/joyeriabd.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
  //si existe buscamos si esta agregado
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
    $encontro = false;
    
    $numero = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++){
      if($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['id']){
        $encontro = true;
        $numero = $i;
      }
    }
    if($encontro == true ){
      $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad'] = $arreglo[$numero]['Cantidad']+1;
      $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
    }else{
      $nombre = "";
      $precio = "";
      $imagen = "";

      $res = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id =" .$_GET['id']) or die($conexion -> error);
      $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
      $nombre = $fila[1];
      $precio = $fila[3];
      $imagen = $fila[4];

      $arregloNuevo = array(
        'Id' => $_GET['id'],
        'Nombre' => $nombre,
        'Precio' => $precio,
        'Imagen' => $imagen,
        'Cantidad' => 1,
      );
      array_push($arreglo, $arregloNuevo);
      $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;
    }
  }

}else{
  //creamos la variable de sesion
  if(isset($_GET['id'] )){
    $nombre = "";
    $precio = "";
    $imagen = "";

    $res = $conexion -> query("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id =" .$_GET['id']) or die($conexion -> error);
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
    $nombre = $fila[1];
    $precio = $fila[3];
    $imagen = $fila[4];

    $arreglo []= array(
        'Id' => $_GET['id'],
        'Nombre' => $nombre,
        'Precio' => $precio,
        'Imagen' => $imagen,
        'Cantidad' => 1,
    );
    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;    
  }


}
?>



en el carrito lo tengo asi, este registro esta dentro de una tabla y voy a llamar los valores que estoy definiendo yo, dentro del carro:


<?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['carrito'])){
                      $arregloCarrito = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                      for($i=0; $i<count($arregloCarrito); $i++){

                      ?>
                      <tr>
                        <td class="product-thumbnail">
                          <img src="images/<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Imagen']; ?>" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
                        </td>
                        <td class="product-name">
                          <h2 class="h5 text-black"><?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Nombre']; ?></h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>$<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Precio']; ?></td>
                        <td>
                          <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 120px;">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-minus" type="button">&minus;</button>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" 
                               value="<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?>" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon" aria-describedby="button-addon1">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-primary js-btn-plus" type="button">&plus;</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>$<?php echo $arregloCarrito[$i]['Precio'] * $arregloCarrito[$i]['Cantidad']; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Eliminar</a></td>
                      </tr>
                    
                      <?php
                      } 
                    }
                  ?>




Al menos yo, no entiendo bien que es lo que pides. Puedes explicar un poco mejor? Pulsa en [edit] tu pregunta plissss

No relacionado con la pregunta en sí: lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo prevenirla. El código compartido es potencialmente vulnerable a este tipo de ataques y no debería utilizarse en entornos de producción por motivos de seguridad. Por ejemplo, ¿qué ocurriría si el valor del parámetro id es algo en plan 0; DELETE FROM productos?
